# Find Length=2 cell in a given range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have these two rows with an image path.
[image]
In Columns D-H i have only one cell that his length is 2.

I need to find it and do formulas based on it, and I would prefer not writing 5 times "IF", any quick way to find it?

Comment: What is your question? Find which column has the length 2?

Comment: return the contents of the cell with the length of the 2

Comment: I remember you asked another question of how to split the test string in Column A into separate texts. Given the pattern of your text string in Column A, you might use this formula (presume your text strings are stored in Column A and want to enter this formula in Column B) to find the **2-Character Length Text**: `{=INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",100)),ROW(1:100)*100,100)),MATCH(2,LEN(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",100)),ROW(1:100)*100,100))),0))}` It is an **Array Formula** so confirm it by press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**. Next time try to tell us your ultimate goal in one post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a non-vba, non-CTE/Array formula way to do this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEN(D1:H1)=2)*COLUMN(D1:H1))
```

Will spit out the number of the column that has a length of 2. If more than one column fulfills this criteria then you will get back garbage. So don't do that.

You can pop that into Index() to get the value that was hit:

```
=INDEX(A1:H1, 1, SUMPRODUCT((LEN(D1:H1)=2)*COLUMN(D1:H1)))
```

Comment: =INDEX(A1:H1, 1, SUMPRODUCT((LEN(D1:H1)=2)*COLUMN(D1:H1)))
this is very good.


  in the same way, how can i get the cell left to the Len=2 cell and the cell right to  the Len=2 cell ?

Comment: That `SumProduct` formula is going to return the column number where the hit was. You can put `+1` or `-1` after that formula in the `Index()` formula to get the prior or next column's value.

Comment: awesome, you helped me a lot!

Comment: What is a CTE formula?  Same as a CSE?

Comment: Too much sql for me. I meant cse.

Answer (score 5):

It's unclear what you're asking but it seems like you're just trying to figure out which column has a string with a length of 2 characters.

If this is the case use this formula (assuming your data starts in row 2 of the columns you mentioned):

`=match(2,len(D2:H2),0)` However, when you write this hit `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`

Which will give you `{=match(2,len(D2:H2),0)}` this is an array formula you must carry down. This will give you the relative column of the string with 2 as its length. Relative meaning, if the criteria is met in column D, it will return 1 (instead of 4).

If you want the value, just use an Index match like so, using the same `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` I mentioned earlier.

`{=index(D2:H2,match(2,len(D2:H2),0))}`

Comment: You could also try: `=INDEX(D2:H2,MATCH(2,INDEX(LEN(D2:H2),),0))` to make it enter normally. And avoid Sumproduct.

Comment: @JvdV I didn't use a `sumproduct` formula.

Comment: I know, but OP does if he goes with the other option ;)

Comment: @Jvdv good looks! just wanted to make sure you didn't mean to comment on that answer.

Comment: both answers work, @JvdV can you please tell me why should I avoid SUMPRODUCT?

Comment: @Assaf, the other answer is fine. No need to avoid `SUMPRODUCT` per se, but `INDEX` & `MATCH` is a very fast combination. When the need to enter as CSE is gone, I personally wouldn't go with `SUMPRODUCT` (as both still remain array formulas). Matter of preference I guess.

Comment: @JvdV that's a nice suggestion (wrapping the array-formula `Match`) in `Index()` as a substitute for the cumbersome `sumproduct()` answer :) @Assaf, `sumproduct()` can be heavy on the CPU so if you are going to copy this down to many rows then you *may* find the index(match())` version to be more performant. It may just come down to preference though too :)

Comment: Thank you for that, index match it is. :)